# Web App to run Mac OS X Program and upload result to server

Tags: javascript, java, mysql, excel, macos

Oke so this is a bit of a complicated issue,

I have a Mac OS X app, (made with Java). I want a website that sends out a API/terminal/email, basically anything to the Mac. Once the Mac gets the 'go' it run the application and once the results are gathered (it is an excel file) I want to Mac to upload the results to the web server or database. That way the results are visible on the website.

So far I know it is possible, I can use a Python script that runs and makes sure my Mac App runs and it can use some If this, then that logic in order to upload the results.

However, it all seems like a load of work for a rather 'simply' thing. So I was wondering if somebody here knowns a bit more about this and could, possibly, point me in a better direction.

Comment: I'm not sure i understand correctly, Why can't you do a Http request to your API once your results is gathered ?&

Comment: If it's a Java application that's server-driven rather than user-driven, why are you running it on a Mac? Why not run it on the server that runs the web site? What happens if the Mac is shut down, or your Internet connection at home is down? I assume the Mac is not a server machine.

Comment: Well these are the type of things I'm trying to figure out. I have developed a Java App, Ported it as a Mac OSX app. But now I have some people that want to use the logic of said App but as a web app. So I was wondering maybe it is easy to just have a website do a call to my mac OSX, run the script and post the results back the site. The mac is not a server machine but I might setup an old mac as server machine if that helps.

Comment: It's just not the way things are done unless there is a compelling reason to do so (e.g. the Java application runs something that is unique to OSX). Otherwise, you should forget about the MacOS X, and try to run your Java on a proper server that's accessible to all, wrapping it in Spring Boot for web API access, or something like that.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Well the thing is, I'm really new to Java. I wasn't even aware it could be used on websites. Do you maybe have some resources about using Java on a proper server and getting the data from that server?

Comment: Also to keep in mind, the App is a GUI app so it cannot work with Terminal commands, thats why I'm also wondering if it could work standalone and just communicates with APIs.

Comment: No, not really, that's a huge research topic. Try googling "Building web applications with Java" and work from there.